# SQL row_number() with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following information in SQL Server table:

[image]

How can I add C1-C2-C3-C4 columns? To do this each colum has different conditions. I'm using `row_number() order by id_pv desc`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `CASE` statement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can do this with nested case statements -- both in the `partition by` clause and outside the `row_number()`.  For the first column:

```
select t.*,
       (case when expiry_date > @somdate and
                  row_number() over (partition by cod_suc, cod_ramo,
                                                  (case when expiry_date > @somdate then 1 else 0 end)
                                     order by id_pv desc) as col1
              then 1 else 0
         end)
from table t;
```

Comment: Perfect!!! I share what I did in the case of c3: `(case
 when expiry_date >= @somedate and t.cod_grupo = 4 and row_number() over (partition by t.cod_suc, t.cod_ramo, t.nro_pol,
   (case
    when expiry_date >= @somedate and t.cod_grupo = 4 then 1
    else 0
   end)
   order by t.id_pv desc) = 1 then 1
    else 0
end),`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your example you want it to place 0 when your conditions are not met, and the row number otherwise, try:

```
Select [your columns]
, case when ExpiryDate >= @someDate then row_number() 
    over (order by [list of columns]) 
    else 0 end as c1
, case when ExpiryDate >= @someDate and Cod_grupo = 4 then row_number() 
    over (order by [other list of columns]) 
    else 0 end as c2
```

Comment: I just need `row_number()` counts depending on colums. So, if I add `partition by`, `row_number()` do not work

Comment: I'm trying this code for C3 `(case
 when t.fec_vig_hasta >= @varFechaHasta and t.cod_grupo_endo = 4 then
  case
   when row_number() over (partition by t.cod_suc, t.cod_ramo_comercial, t.nro_pol order by t.id_pv) = 1 then 1
   else 0
  end
 else 0
end) as 'C3'`

Comment: Ohh, are you just trying to insert 1 when a row is the top result and 0 otherwise?  You might have better luck with taking the max over the partition and then comparing.  Like    case when number = max(number) over (partition by ...) then 1 else 0 end

Comment: Can you share an example. I'm confused

Comment: Pretty similar to the example above mine, by Gordon Linoff.